How to restart when remotely connected with xrdp
I use xrdp to connect to ubuntu with xorg. I have noticed that in the GUI restart and shut down are disabled. When I run sudo reboot in the terminal, I cannot connect anymore. Also locally the screen is black and I need to do a force restart. How could I correctly restart ubuntu?

The local screen shouldn't be black though, and that may have nothing to do with RDP, what happens if you run sudo reboot directly on the machine, without any active RDP connection? Does it still get stuck? If so, try and spam ESC immediately after having issued the reboot command (hopefully you'll manage to get one through before it gets stuck) to see exactly what job is getting stuck and report back so that we can try and help you out

sudo shutdown    {providing a delay time} would bring the system down however, if you can't physically get to the machine, that would present a problem.
OK so you really need reboot but you need a delay.  Consider running the job with the At facility, that lets you run something at a future time - say in three minutes.  Before then you have time to log out and thus not get caught in the middle of a reboot.  I didn't try reboot within an at job but did confirm you can run something with root privilege.  Oh - to end the stream of lines to at - use Ctrl-D.  For you it would be a one liner with at.  The total sequence is as follows [assuming it is now 10:15 in the morning]
sudo at 10:22
reboot
{ here you need that Ctrl-d }
now be sure you get off the system before 10:22 so as not to be caught in the reboot
